# Scraping data using Selenium and BeutifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=2203-Delhi,+IN')
soup= BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select('.name'):
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

I want to print the name of company but, It does not print any thing why?

Comment: I think, you should need to add chorme driver path into `webdriver.Chrome("PATH")`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the CSS selector (.name) is not valid for company names. If you want to print the names of the companies. You should use `('.styles_companyName__9g4zC span')`.

**Code:**

```
for item in soup.select('.styles_companyName__9g4zC span'):
    print(item.text)
```

Moreover, you should also give the `executable_path` parameter to the webdriver.Chrome.